# Big Bank Heist: Does 'the Beast' benefit from technician skills?

Tags: payday-2

When the drill "The Beast" in the Big Bank job is set up by a technician, does the drill benefit from any unlocked skills (e.g. auto restart from "Hardware Expert"-skill or 15% efficiency from the "Drill Sergeant"-skill)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Skills do not benefit "The Beast" as far as I am aware, we've shad the drill set up by people without any drill skills and those will maxed out drill skills and there is no change in drill time and the drill will never restart itself.